# Cannot download zipped images. CRC32 always 00000000

Tags: codeigniter, zip, crc32

I created a simple code with codeigniter to download zipped up image files.  It seems to work but when I try to open the downloaded zip file the crc32 is always 00000000 and the file/files cannot be extracted.  I tried doing the same thing with text files and that works fine.  (the crc32 is not 000000000)

Code:

```
$path = 'test/014.jpg';
$this->zip->read_file($path);
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

I also tried the following:

```
$path = 'test';
$this->zip->read_dir($path);
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

I followed the instructions in the user guide below:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/zip.html

In the example given in the user guide it zips up a jpg file and downloads it and this is exactly what I'm trying to do.  It seems like this should be really straight forward, however it is not working.

I tried adding the following:

```
$this->zip->archive('my_backup.zip');
```

As described here:

[Unable to open zip file, codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050441/unable-to-open-zip-file-codeigniter)

However this did not help

I'm using WAMP on windows 7, tried firefox and chrome

Any help with this is greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: What is the return value from read_file?

Comment: Make sure you are not sending any echos or displays in the controller because it would switch the mode from binary to ASCII. This may explain why it works for an ASCII text file but not for a zip. Check the construct, disable any layouts or themes that may autoload, etc.